# Как убрать ограничение по времени ожидания ответа websocket сервера?

Tags: python, websocket

Сервер и клиент взаимодействуют по websocket-ам. Сервер генерирует большой объем данных (минут 40) и отправляет на клиент, но при генерации появляется ошибка, что websocket сервер разорвал соединение. Сервер написан на python (websockets, asyncio), клиент на javascript (WebSocket). Можно как-нибудь удалить ограничение по  времени ожидания?

Comment: Попробуйте на сервере установить параметр ```timeout``` для ```websockets.serve()```, чтобы увеличить время ожидания соединения. Также посмотрите настройки сервера, чтобы они не ограничивали время для WebSocket соединений. 
На клиенте попробуйте установить параметр ```timeout``` для ```WebSocket``` в JavaScript.

Comment: добавил параметр timeout=float('inf') в websockets.serve, щас будем тестировать

Comment: да, все получилось, спасибо

Comment: Если всё получилось, поставьте, пожалуйста, плюс моему комментарию. Спасибо.